# Boost asio TCP IP asio class compile error with Visual Studio. Error: C2228: left of '.close' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, class, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm trying to follow the steps provided in this page

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html

However, at some point the code does not compile, and gives me the specified error. I can't understand what kind of conflict it is. The object tcpsock doesn't seem to be correctly created. Please check my code:

```
io_service io_tcp;
tcp::resolver resolverObject(io_tcp);
tcp::resolver::query queryObject(argv[1], "daytime");
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolverObject.resolve(queryObject);
tcp::resolver::iterator end; //default constructor is end iterator

tcp::socket tcpsock(io_service);
boost::system::error_code socketError = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

while (socketError && endpoint_iterator != end)
{
    //Apparently, the object isn't created correctly
    tcpsock.close(); //error happenes here
    tcpsock.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, socketError); //error happenes here too
}
if (socketError)
    throw boost::system::system_error(socketError);
```

Thank you for any efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing `tcpsock` with the type `io_service`, not with the variable `io_tcp`.

Comment: What a stupid mistake! see? now 2 hours are wasted for a stupid mistake!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: when following an example, it can be tricky when you rename variables ;-)

Comment: Agreed! I'll try to be more careful. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I also found this compile error but from a different angle given the following:

```
    boost::asio::read(socket, replyBuf, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
```

Compared to the correct:

```
boost::asio::read(*socket, replyBuf, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
```

Notice the need the de-reference the socket.
It seems boost's use of common base types prevents the usual intellisense errors.

In the future I recommend adding a null check before use for the args of a boost type at runtime.